# Quickly redistribute number of words/character per line in VIM

Tags: vim, text

For text writing in `vim`, when I need to edit a line/add some new text, the number of words per line gets all out of whack.

Is there a way of quickly re-adjusting/line-wrapping to evenly disperse the number of words per line in VIM?

Example with 80 character auto-line-wrapping:

**Before edit**

```
This is something that I have writting with automatic line-wrapping before I 
have edited the file. I'll write some more just for demonstration purposes for
this whole line wrapping problem of mine.
```

**After edit**

```
This is something that I have writting with automatic line-wrapping after I
have edited the file. I'm demonstrating
this whole line wrapping problem of mine.
```

Manually fixing these is a bore, especially if I fix it and go on to edit things again.

**My dream**

It would be perfect if I could visually select a number of lines using `shit+v`, and then automatically distribute the number of words per line.

Comment: in your "after edit" how many lines in your buffer? are all text in a single line?

Comment: The auto-wrap will move text beyond a defined limit (80 characters above) to the next line, so they are not on a single line. I prefer this, as it makes navigating text much easier with cursor move commands (i.e. `h`,`j`,`k`,`l`, etc.), amongst other things.

Comment: Lines in the buffer could vary, I'm looking for a general approach for different files I do text editing in (e.g. plain text, LaTeX, reStructuredText, MarkDown, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `textwidth` option  (or `tw` for short) for your desired
width. Lets say 80.

```
:set tw=80
```

Now, use  either the  built-in formatter  or your  custom one,  with the
command `gq`. Check the help for  `gq`, `gw`, and `'formatprg'` to known
more. This is used with a  motion. So to reformat the current paragraph,
do `gqip`.  The whole text,  `gggqG` (cursor  to top (`gg`)  then format
until bottom). And all other sorts off motion.

Additionally, please explore the help  for format options (`:h 'fo'` and
`:h fo-table`).  A particular interesting option  for you is `a`.  So if
you do:

```
:set tw=80
:set fo+=a
```

Now you don't even need to  reformat nothing. Vim will keep checking the
width of the line as you type  and reformatting your paragraph on the go
by inserting or removing newlines.

I  like the  flexibility of  external programs,  and also  recommend you
checking them out. This answer's MarkDown for example was formatted with
the UNIX program *par*. Check the original text.

Comment: Excellent with auto reformatting. Choosing this as the best answer for the additional information. Thanks still to Xavier!

Comment: I've now tried the auto-formatting it is works great for my purposes.

Comment: @ryanjdillon Nice to know! Glad that it helped you. Best wishes

Answer (score 5):

- <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to select the current paragraph, then
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>to reformat the paragraph using textwidth.

or

- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to combine an operator and a range (see `:help text-objects`for more details)

If you use it often, you can probably remap a new command that would execute the two previously mentioned commands.

See `:help gq`for more details.

Comment: This works with `shift+v` too. Dreams do come true. Thanks Xavier!!! This is a game changer for me :)

Comment: `vip` + `gq` could be `gqip` instead.